# C++ - Access map reference

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, dictionary, reference

Sorry. a trivial question on reference map access

if I have:

```
map<int,string> *items= new map<int,string>();
```

I do this?

```
string x = &items[100];
```

Comment: In that code, `items` is not a reference but a pointer.

Comment: Don't say `new`. Ever. (Unless you understand what you're doing, which you can tell by the fact that you feel comfortable ignoring this advice.)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but `&items[100]` means - give me the address of a 100-th map in a dynamically allocated array of maps called items. However, since you allocate only a single map (and not an array of maps) this is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first I ask; why are you dynamically allocating your map?  It kind of defeats the purpose of using it in the first place.  The map will internally use dynamic allocation for it's items, but the map itself is cheap and you lose the ability to deterministically manage its memory via scope.  So, your code becomes:

```
map<int,string> my_map;
my_map[100] = "some string";
string x = items[100];
```

Otherwise you need to dereference the map pointer first.

```
string x = (*my_map)[100];
```

Really though... don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you must have:

```
map<int,string> *items= new map<int,string>();
```

You do this:

```
string x = (*items)[100];
```

If you could have instead:

```
map<int,string> items;
```

You would do this:

```
string x = items[100];
```